# "this.startLoginAnimatioon is not a function" error

Tags: typescript

I am writing a login system with typescript and am running into an error that I cant seem to understand why its happening. so basically: 
[image]

When the runtime reaches the this.startLoginAnimation() function call in the attemptLogin() function it throws:[image]
when clearly this is a function, i may also add that visual studio code does not complain about it.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript#red-flags-for-this

Answer (score 1):

> this.startLoginAnimation is not a function” error

`this` depends on how you call the function. Quick fix, use an arrow:

```
startLoginAnimation = () => {
}
```

## More

There are lots of resources on `this`. [Here is a quick video about `this` in TypeScript classes](https://egghead.io/lessons/typescript-make-usages-of-this-safe-in-class-methods).

Comment: It still throw's the same error when I use an arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

I Found the solution, I tested what 'this' equal's and it was referring to an HTMLElement type, thanks for the link to that website, though, it seems like a promising learning resource!

for anyone having a similar problem this is what I did:
instead if form.addEventListener('submit', this.attemptLogin);
i did as follow's:
[image]